# How to add user to an existing distribution list using Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to add user to an existing DL using outlook VBA. For example. I have a DL which has email id as  "testdl@contoso.com" and want add an existing user name "John.Wick@contoso.com". I also know that I can use DistListItem.AddMember to add user to an existing DL. But I am getting idea to find the existing distribution list. Please help me with this.

```
Sub Add_User_To_DL()
Dim myNameSpace AS Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolder AS Outlook.Folder
Dim myDistList AS Outlook.DistListItem
Dim myFolderItems AS Outlook.Items
Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
myFolder.Display    
End Sub
```

But this code just opens Contacts group window. What I want is , to open the specified DL and then add specified member to DL.

Comment: Hi, could you show us some examples what exactly are you trying to achieve? I'm not sure if you have issues with running `DistListItem.AddMember` or something else

Comment: @lukaszberwid I have updated the code in the question

Comment: By looking at the code it should be opening olFolderContacts. Where did you define `olFolderContacts`?

Comment: This olFolderContacts, by default opens the DL where I am one of the member of the DL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a distribution list that includes a specific address.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find_ContactGroup_Given_Member()

    Dim ContactGroup As String
    
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objContactsFolder As Folder
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set objContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    
    For Each objItem In objContactsFolder.Items
    
        If TypeOf objItem Is DistListItem Then
       
            Debug.Print objItem.DLName
            
            For i = 1 To objItem.MemberCount
                
                If objItem.GetMember(I).Address = "testdl@contoso.com" Then
                    Debug.Print objItem.GetMember(i).Name
                    objItem.Display
                End If
                
            Next i
        
        End If
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

---

To reference a distribution list:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DistListDisplay()

Dim strDistListName As String
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objContactsFolder As Folder
Dim objContactGroup As DistListItem
Dim bFound As Boolean

strDistListName = InputBox("Name of an existing distribution list.", , "Test")

If Len(strDistListName) = 0 Then Exit Sub   ' Cancel

Set objContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    
For Each objItem In objContactsFolder.Items
    If TypeOf objItem Is DistListItem Then
        If objItem.DLName = strDistListName Then
            Set objContactGroup = objItem
            With objContactGroup
                .Display
                bFound = True
                Exit For
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next

If bFound = False Then
    MsgBox strDistListName & " not found."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Above code is able to find the existing DL with name and if I specify the email id, it does not find..Is there any way, I can search the DL using email id because it will be unique and then I can add a member in that DL